# Get renderings for a placholder

Tags: presentation, placeholders

I am trying to create a report of all placeholders and the rendering options available inside them. For this, I want to get all renderings within a placeholder.

Is there a way get I can get all the renderings available in a placeholder in Sitecore using the Sitecore API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
private IEnumerable<Sitecore.Data.Items.RenderingItem> GetRenderings(string placeholderKey, Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item)
{
  Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference[] renderings = GetRenderingReferences(item, "default");
  foreach (var rendering in renderings)
  {
    if (rendering.Placeholder == placeholderKey)
    {
      yield return rendering.RenderingItem;
    }
  }
}


private Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference[] GetRenderingReferences(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item, string deviceName)
{
  Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField layoutField = item.Fields["__renderings"];
  Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference[] renderings = layoutField.GetReferences(GetDeviceItem(item.Database, deviceName));
  return renderings;
}
```

Here you can find multiple methods about placeholders API: https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/get-sitecore-placeholders-and-rendering-hierarchy-from-a-sitecore-item/

Comment: Is there a way I can use this code without specifying an item and only a placeholder key?

Comment: nope, because "__renderings" field is a field on an item.

Comment: Alright. I was trying to avoid using an item to get the renderings but I haven't seen any other way so I will use some existing items as examples.